# Can I select data ordered by a field a way that it values would be different in consecutive rows?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table of products with manufacturers field and I need to extract data so that two manufacturers with same id won't stay together.
For example:

```
id prod_id manf_id
1 100 300
2 101 300
3 102 400
4 103 400
5 103 500
```

So that result would look smth like:

```
1 100 300
3 102 400
5 103 500
2 101 300
4 103 400
```

It doesn't matter too much in the example above if there'll be sequences with ids that has same neighbours (300-400-300) but it would be more interesting to see more complex logic so that a single id would have only one neighbour id of the same type (300-400-500).
If such ordering could not be applied - show data with same consecutive values (300-300-300).

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8ae28/8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this.

```
SELECT Row_number()OVER(partition BY manf_id ORDER BY id) rn, *
FROM   Yourtable
ORDER  BY rn,id
```

Comment: I think the ID column is actually generated by the `ROW_NUMBER()` or should be generated to match these rules.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu In `row_number` you will get three `1's` here which one you will display first

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu - No, thats why `Id` is included in `Order by`

Comment: I'm not asking why it's included in the `ORDER BY`, I'm saying that the OP didn't mention that this column exists, just that he wants the data displayed in that order.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
;with cte as (
select id,prod_id,manuf_id,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by manuf_id order by id) as row_no
from products 
)
select id,prod_id,manuf_id from cte
order by  row_no
```

Comment: I eventually got it. Wow! You're awesome! :)